# Typescript: Define object type without defining types for keys to get keyof

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Here I want to define the type for object value only. In order to get types for keys. Is there any way to get without defining types for each value.

```
const sizes: Record<string, CSSObject>= {
  md: {
    padding: [10, 24],
    fontSize: 'medium',
  },
  xs: {
    padding: [6, 12],
    fontSize: 'small',
  },
  sm: {
    padding: [8, 16],
    fontSize: 'small',
  },
  lg: {
    padding: [14, 30],
    fontSize: 'large',
  },
} as const;

// Expecting 'md' | 'xs' | 'sm' | 'lg'
type Sizes = keyof typeof sizes;

// But it is string
```

Comment: ```const sizes: { [K in keyof typeof sizes]: CSSObject } = {...``` yup kind of this but it's not working, it says *Type parameter 'K' has a circular constraint.*

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the problem, but I think I get it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to infer the keys `'md' | 'xs' | 'sm' | 'lg'` from the object's actual properties, but you also want the type-checker to make sure that the properties' values are of type `CSSObject`.

The problem is that you would need a type annotation on the object literal to check the values are `CSSObject`; but if you use a type annotation then `keyof ...` will get the keys from the annotated type, not the object itself.

The way around this is to use a generic helper function, so that the record's key type is inferred while the value type is specified:

```js
function helper<K extends PropertyKey>(obj: Record<K, CSSObject>): Record<K, CSSObject> {
    return obj;
}

const sizes = helper({
  md: {
    padding: [10, 24],
    fontSize: 'medium',
  },
  // ...
});

type Sizes = keyof typeof sizes;
// 'md' | 'xs' | 'sm' | 'lg'
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgynA8gIwFYQMbCgXigbyjAEMATUgSwDsBzALigCcIyB7KgGxCioFcBbZBEYBtALoAaKADN2wOBQBeEBgGdgjajSgBfANwAoA9N5UsFdlAAWEDpEYAeANJQIAD2AQqpVVAAKjKz2oE4QIAB8ABSsaAwASpisjKTOUvBIaJjA4QCU8YnJqbAIKOhY4QQGUNVMEMC8jFRQMaiGOkYY7OpQqkoQvng2dsKR+FVQ-KQMYzVEZJS0DCIAjAAMUgBMACyS49WyVPJ9DADk-BCUAicS4zo31W6q03tz5FpLAGxSyxu7swdHZSnVT8YgcDjXW73Hr8Z6zEhvRZQEQADm+Hz+NQBCiBUBOILBEOhd3GHHolXh83eyOWWykAGZVpj9nIcSo8RxiIwaBBIdUSTocoYDKBIFA2QMoABrMKsaRQUUQOU9PqqQwAenVeMmJygAB88Y9dQb8fxjRyaCcDEA)

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add on to @kaya3's very helpful answer:

The `helper` function here works specifically with `CSSObject`. I needed to use this helper on multiple objects with different value types, so I wrote a version that lets you pass in any type:

```
function constrainValuesAndInferKeys<V>() {
    return function <K extends PropertyKey>(obj: Record<K, V>) {
        return obj;
    }
}

const sizes = constrainValuesAndInferKeys<CSSProperties>()({
  md: {
    padding: [10, 24],
    fontSize: 'medium',
  },
  // ...
});

type Sizes = keyof typeof sizes;
// 'md' | 'xs' | 'sm' | 'lg'
```

The downside is you have to add that extra `()` in `constrainValuesAndInferKeys<CSSProperties>()({`.