# Is it possible to enforce the type of an object's values without explicitly setting a type for its keys?

Tags: typescript

I want something like this:

```
type Person = { age:number, weight: number}
const people:{[key:infer_the_type]:Person} = {
  mike: {...},
  bob: {...},
}
```

so that if I do this, it works:

```
keyof typeof people // This should be "mike" | "bob"
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Something along the lines of `Record<keyof any, Person>` maybe, but I don't know how to retain the `mike` and `bob` properties elegantly in the type. Need something like `extends`

Comment: Being able to get the string-literal-union type of the keys is one of my key goals so the `any` is not acceptable unfortunately. Otherwise I would have just replaced `infer_the_type` with `string`. I also do not want to have to explicitly create the type because then it's not DRY.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: Define object type without defining types for keys to get keyof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60200486/typescript-define-object-type-without-defining-types-for-keys-to-get-keyof)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get the behavior you're looking for by [annotating](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the type of `people`; once you annotate `people` with a (non-union) type, the compiler will automatically throw away any more specific information it had about the initialized value.  There's a (longstanding) open issue in GitHub, [microsoft/TypeScript#7481](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7481) which asks for something like your `infer_the_type` (especially relevant is [microsoft/TypeScript#38349](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38349) which was closed as a duplicate).  If you want to see that happen, you might want to go to that issue and give it a , but it's not clear when or if this will ever be implemented.

Instead, you can get similar behavior by replacing your type annotation with a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) helper function:

```
const asPeople = 
  <K extends PropertyKey>(people: { [P in K]: Person }) => people;

const people = asPeople({
  mike: { name: "Mike", weight: 150 },
  bob: { name: "Bob", weight: 200 },
}); // okay
```

You can verify that the compiler has inferred the keys of `people`:

```
/* const people: {
    mike: Person;
    bob: Person;
} */
```

And the helper function will report an error if you pass it something unexpected:

```
const badPeople = asPeople({
  alice: { name: "Alice", height: 75 } // error!
  // -------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~
  //  Did you mean to write 'weight'?
})
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbyqghgLYQBcUiw8AlqgOYA0UA7hFbQBbBmoCuhARgigBfAFABjNBSj5EcZGAA20LAB4A0lAgAPYBFQATRLHgKEodRBAA+ABSQFysrgDaMKDSjqAumThI0EQBKTGsoByUIAG5RCSlgcIhHFRk5JMjbbFEoKEIqAGtSHDwiIoAiAFkCiDLGFjZOMgBGAFYABhF6bKh+ZH5nEuIyMoAhPtrmVg4uKAAmNo7hLuEgqKgAenWoZHz8EFj1gCooSVRpCKccbpy8wr8EFFQYnJze-tgHtBjhKEP12NO0n4+AM8kimFSYOUmW6+EUVHERVwBCGUDKAEF4YiJuwpo0oAB2FoiDZbBCmeAAQm6mygAFoGYymcymWEAH4czlcmlbKAAESoBigIGQPFyEHw6GAyGY1D0UAA5PVpgqAPyiFZRIA)

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to create a helper function to do this. It's a little bit ugly since it means having pointless functions floating around at runtime but will get the job done:

```
const getPeople = <P extends PropertyKey>(p: Record<P, Person>) => p;

const typedPeople = getPeople({
  mike: {name: "mike", weight: 32},
  bob: {name: "bob", weight: 6},
})
```

`typedPeople` will be of type `Record<'mike' | 'bob', Person>`.

Alternatively, since this is presumably a static list of names (I don't see how this would work otherwise), it might just be better to create the type beforehand, assming the list is not too long or subject to change:

```
type Names = 'mike' | 'bob';
```

Even more alternatively, I am a little suspicious of the need to explicitly type `people` at all. As you've already demonstrated, you can use `keyof` to get the names out of the object after instantiating it, so anywhere it's going to get used should have the types already available.

Comment: The example was just to demonstrate the behavior I want; the actual types/keys I use are a lot more complicated